# How To Insert An Emoticon In C# For A Chat

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr, emoticons

I am trying to develop a chat application using SignalR. Now I want to integrate Emoticons(smiles) in that.

Can any one help me? I have no idea how to do it, my chat application is working correctly I just need to add emoticons.

Comment: Could you do a search and replace kinda thing where you replace, say, ":)" with and img tag before writing it to your output div? `var res = 'this is a test :)'.replace(/\:\)/g, "<img src='smiley.png' alt=':)'/>");`

Comment: Use a grammar parser like [NPEG](https://github.com/leblancmeneses/NPEG) to identify emoticons. `Hey Ravi :)` should create an emoticon whereas `A(:) = 1` should *not* identify the `:)` as an emoticon because it has a matching parenthesis.